# How to create sorted object by date

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to solve an issue that requires the sort of an array of objects containing information. For example, transform this:

```
[
{ 
  name: 'test1',
  date: '2019-02-18T08:33:01.000Z',
},
{ 
  name: 'test2',
  date: '2019-02-19T08:33:01.000Z',
},
{ 
  name: 'test3',
  date: '2019-02-19T08:33:01.000Z',
},
]
```

To this:

```
{
 '2019-02-18':{
   name: 'test1'
},
 '2019-02-19':[
 {
   name: 'test2',
 },
 {
   name: 'test3',
 }
]
}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient method to groupby on a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects)

Comment: We would be happy to help you, but we are less keen on doing work *for* you.  Please share with us what you have so far, so we can help you get it working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want an array of objects for every grouped `date`. One alternative is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in conjunction with [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
const input = [
  {name: 'test1', date: '2019-02-18T08:33:01.000Z'},
  {name: 'test2', date: '2019-02-19T08:33:01.000Z'},
  {name: 'test3', date: '2019-02-19T08:33:01.000Z'}
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, {name, date}) =>
{
    let [m, d] = date.match(/(.+)T/);
    acc[d] = [...(acc[d] || []), {name}];
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is more a group by problem than a sort. Object keys are unsorted, also.

```js
function groupByDate(data) {
  let result = {};
  
  data.forEach((el) => {
    let datePart = el.date.split("T")[0];
    let value = result[datePart]
    if(value) {
      result[datePart].push({name: el.name})
    } else {
      result[datePart] = [{name: el.name}]
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}


var dates = [
{ 
  name: 'test1',
  date: '2019-02-18T08:33:01.000Z',
},
{ 
  name: 'test2',
  date: '2019-02-19T08:33:01.000Z',
},
{ 
  name: 'test3',
  date: '2019-02-19T08:33:01.000Z',
},
];

console.log(groupByDate(dates));
```

Comment: Not sure about why this was downvoted, it achieves the same results as a map reduce using for loop instead.